# SQL - Select customer's orders with by adding and distinct products

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have 3 tables :

**CUSTOMERS :**

```
CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME
```

**ORDERS :**

```
ORDER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | QUANTITY | PRICE
```

**PRODUCTS :**

```
PRODUCT_ID | NAME | PRICE
```

I would like to list all products ordered by a customer but with adding all quantities.

**Here is the result I would like to have** :

```
CUSTOMER ID | PRODUCT_ID(1) | QUANTITIES (SUM)

CUSTOMER ID | PRODUCT_ID(2) | QUANTITIES (SUM)

CUSTOMER ID | PRODUCT_ID(3) | QUANTITIES (SUM)

CUSTOMER ID | PRODUCT_ID(4) | QUANTITIES (SUM)
```

**Here is my actual request which only list all orders with all the informations (without SUM) :**

```
SELECT CUS.*, ORD.*, PRO.*

FROM `customers` CUS

LEFT JOIN `orders` ORD
ON ORD.customer_id = CUS.customer_id

LEFT JOIN `products` PRO
ON PRO.product_id = ORD.product_id 

WHERE CUS.customer_id = 4697
```

Thank you

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a sum and a group by, only selecting the columns you want would make it easier too.

```
select customer_id, product_id, sum(quantity)
FROM `customers` CUS

LEFT JOIN `orders` ORD
ON ORD.customer_id = CUS.customer_id

LEFT JOIN `products` PRO
ON PRO.product_id = ORD.product_id 

WHERE CUS.customer_id = 4697
group by customer_id, product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    PRO.product_name,
    ROUND(SUM(ORD.price),2),
    ROUND(SUM(ORD.quantity), 2)

FROM ORDERS ORD

LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS PRO
ON PRO.product_id = ORD.product_id

WHERE ORD.customer_id = 4697

GROUP BY ORD.product_id
```

Thank you ;)